# It is possible to write only WriteLine instead of Console.WriteLine in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, console-application

I'm  a completely noob and a begginer programmer in  C# but I was reading about Roslyn and 'What's new in C# 7.0' and I found something very interesting that I can't find out the answer I need.

In this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/), all the examples given contain something like `WriteLine("something");` instead of `Console.WriteLine("something");`, for example:

```
public void PrintCoordinates(Point p)
{
  p.GetCoordinates(out int x, out int y);
  WriteLine($"({x}, {y})");
}
```

My question is: How can I do that?

Would something like this work?

```
public static void WriteLine(string v) => Console.WriteLine(v);
```

Comment: I would say that this isn't related to roslyn, so you might want to remove the tag.

Comment: Ok. Done. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try [using static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive) directive:

```
 using static System.Console;

 ...

 WriteLine("some text");
```

Answer (score 10):

Starting with C# 6.0, this is possible:

```
using static System.Console;
```

However, previous versions of C# do not have static imports.

Answer (score 6):

You can use an `Action`:

```
Action<string> WriteLine = (text) => Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try to implement that!